# AngularJs: call function from directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This seems simple enough and I have it working to some degree but there's some issues with my solution.

The scenario is that I want to pass a function (`toggleValue()`) to a directive and then call that function via ngChange from within the directive template. The basic setup is:

```
// html
<div class="my-directive" ng-model="my_model" ng-change="toggleValue()"></div>

// angular directive
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
      scope: {
        restrict: 'C',
        model: '=ngModel',
        action: '=ngChange'
      },
      template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" ng-change="action">'
  }
}
```

This is a bit over-simplified since it's out of context but it demonstrates what I'm trying to do. This also works. The issue with it is that it gets called several times -- even before it's explicitly called. This appears to be due to the 2-way binding on the action. As I understand, & should be used for isolating methods but when I change action to `'&ngChange'` the function, toggleValue(), never gets called at all.

I tried incorporating the solution at [Call a controller function from a directive without isolated scope in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583004/call-an-angularjs-controller-function-from-a-directive-without-isolated-scope) but didn't have any success. Using `$apply()` gave me a $digest error and using `$eval()` had no response.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$eval(attrs.action);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a function, you need to use `&` not `=` in the scope definition:

```
action: '&ngChange'
```

Then you need to call the action in the directive template:

```
ng-change="action()"
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Didn't think it'd be as easy as adding parenthesis. Thanks.