# Function passed to isolate scope doesn't receive arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass the function(`removeItem`) to the the isolate scope of the directive, and then call this function inside the directive's template, however that function gets called but without the arguments. I tried like this:

```
<my-directive remove="removeItem(item)"></my-directive>
```

place where `removeItem` is defined:

```
scope.removeItem = function(item) {
  console.log('item removed');
}
```

isolate scope:

```
scope: {
    remove: "&"
}
```

and directive template:

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in allItems | selectedItemFilter" >
   <label>{{ item.description }}</label>
   <div>
     <button ng-click="remove(item)"> Remove</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

So when the remove button is clicked, the actual `removeItem` is called, but without the item argument, which is undefined. I tried also with passing the simple string argument but `removeItem` never gets it, it is also undefined. What could cause this behaviour ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs pass function from Controller to Directive (or call controller function from directive) - with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666374/angularjs-pass-function-from-controller-to-directive-or-call-controller-functio)

Comment: TL;DR ~ you should have `ng-click="remove({item: item})"` in your directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's a little un-intuitive in this regard. You actually need to specify your argument name (in the view) like so:

```
<button ng-click="remove({item: item})">
```

Comment: No problem. :) This has burned me before as well.