# API for AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui

I want to implement Angular widgets similar to KendoUI.
In kendo we implement the widgets by Angular directives as follows

HTML

```
    <input kendo-numerictextbox k-min=1 k-max=5 k-on-spin="valueChanged(kendoEvent)">
```

k-min -> this can be implemented by reading the Attrs in the directives and modifying the Element

k-on-spin ->whenever value is changed we call this valueChanged() function which can then be implemented in the end users Angular controller as follows

```
$scope.valueChanged = function(e){
console.log(e.event.target.tagName)};
```

Question: how to implement the k-on-spin in Angular directive, so that if user wants they can hook up their function when this event occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call an AngularJS Controller Function from a directive without isolated scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583004/call-an-angularjs-controller-function-from-a-directive-without-isolated-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$eval` or `$apply` to get AngularJS to evaluate your function.

You can read more about`$apply` [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

There has already been a question dealing with this problem and a good answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599982/4360457)