# AngularJS directive scope function not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created the following directive:

```
app.directive("autoLoad", function ($window) {
    return { 
        scope: {
            do: '&'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var scroller = element[0];
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 100)) {
                    console.log("GOT HERE!");
                    scope.do(); // LOAD POSTS
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This directive should call the do function when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. This is the div that uses the directive:

```
<body ng-app="storeApp" layout="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-cloak">
...
<div flex layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main"
    class="md-whiteframe-z2" auto-Load do="doSomething()">
```

The controller looks like this:

```
app.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, controllerManager) {
    ...

    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        console.log("PLEASE WORK!");
    };
});
```

When I reach the bottom of the page, GOT HERE is being printed, but the second statement is never shown. Why is the function in the controller not being called?

EDIT: I am using tabs, each of which has a different controller. So the main controller that is applied to the body object, actually does not have the doSomething function inside it:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : "/home",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).state('top', {
        url : "/top",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'TopCtrl'
    }).state('trending', {
        url : "/trending",
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : 'TrendingCtrl'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $location, $log) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
        switch (current) {
        case 0:
            $location.url("/home");
            break;
        case 1:
            $location.url("/top");
            break;
       case 2:
            $location.url("/trending");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

The do something function is actually part of each of the sub controllers: HomeCtrl, TopCtrl etc.

The problem seeems to be that the scope is defined by the MainCtrl rather than whatever tab it is currently on. How can this be changed?

Comment: remove " after ng-cloak in the body TAG

Comment: first of all fix some issues. "auto-load" instead of "auto-Load" in your HTML, restrict your directive in the right way

Comment: See in this Link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583004/angularjs-call-a-controller-function-from-a-directive-without-isolated-scope

Comment: @CodeNashor because of the way browser work, casing information is lost on attribute names, so you can in fact use `auto-Load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , you really need to use service or factory for that, but if you still want to use expression binding, move your code from link function to directive controller ( see jsbin https://jsbin.com/nohotizefi/edit?html,js,output)

```
 app.directive("autoLoad", function ($window) {
return { 
    scope: {
        do: '&'
    },
    controller : function($scope, $element) {
        var scroller = $element;
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 100)) {
                console.log("GOT HERE!");
                $scope.do(); // LOAD POSTS
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

Comment: I get an error on this line:  var scroller = scope.el;
Saying scope is undefined.

Comment: It is still only printing the first thing. I also tried $scope.$eval($scope.do()).

Comment: I have edited the question with some relevant information. I am using multiple controllers, this may change things.