# Angularjs conditional nested directive with templateurl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, wizard, directive

I'm trying to create a conditional nested directive.
The goal is to print a form with wizardmode or the full form.

For the wizard I use https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

my html site:

```
  <wizard on-finish="saveit()"> 
    <div ng-repeat="element in filtered = (lang | langFilter:data.review.form_elements) | orderBy:'element_order'">

        <div btwizard></div>

    </div>
  </wizard>
```

First directive:

```
app.directive "btwizard", [ "$compile", ($compile) ->
  transclude: true
  scope: false
  replace: false
  templateUrl: "/assets/template/review_form.html"
  link: (scope,element,attrs,ctrl, transclude) ->
    if (scope.data.review.config.wizardmode)
      element.find('inner').replaceWith(element.children())
      $compile(element.contents())(scope)


return

]
```

The templateUrl is:

```
<inner>
   <div class="row">
       someform html
   </div>
</inner>
```

I'm trying to replace `<inner>` with the contents of the url `elemenet.children()` depending on the `wizardmode` value

the second directive replaces `<inner>` with the wizardsteps html:

```
  app.directive "inner", [ "$compile", ($compile) ->
    restrict: "E"
    replace: false
    scope: false
    transclude: true
    template: "<wz-step title='Starting'><div ng-transclude></div></wz-step>"


   ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Update: I made a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qOhZuVyi3oUVWBftIxBV?p=preview

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Can you reproduce this within [runnable codesnippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1)?

Comment: Basically it's a question of communication between directives.  You can have them listen for an event in inner and broadcast event in btwizard.  [You can see this more more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199212/angularjs-broadcast-event-from-directive) or [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: I added a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qOhZuVyi3oUVWBftIxBV?p=preview

basically, there is no event triggered by hand, these directives are just embeded, this should possible with the same scope (scope=false)