# AngularJS child directive depending on parent directive reusability

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's define a trivial scenario where a blog has a list of `Post`s, each with `Comment`s and other `Object`s.

In structuring the `Post` page, I can image defining the following elements:

```
<post post="post"></post>
<comments post="post"></comments>
<objects post="post"></objects>
```

or:

```
<post post="post">
    <comments></comments>
    <objects></objects>
</post>
```

To provide reusability, each directive associated to an element has its own isolated scope.

Considering then for example the directive associated to `<comments>`, I can supply it with an `Add` button, a `Reload comments` button etc. That's easy, as long as its functions are limited to its own scope.

`Comment`s are loaded when `Post` is first loaded, in the `link` method of the directive associated to `<comments>`. How can i trigger `Comment`s reloading when (the parent) `Post` changes?

1. In the directive associated to `<comments>`, should I place a `scope.$watch('post')` to listen when the associated `Post` changes and trigger on change the `Comment`s reloading?
2. Should I create a `register` function in the `Post` directive, where `Comment`s and `Object`s subscribe their own controllers, and are notified from a `Post` function when they need to be reloaded? That is, a manually implemented Observer pattern.
3. `$broadcast` and `$on`? Not sure how to implement them with isolated scopes.

Comment: I'm unsure of your architecture in terms of data but I think if you were to load comments as objects embedded in posts, your comment directive could just bind to the posts comments collection and the changes would propagate to your UI automatically. Edit: This blog post explains nicely https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate thing to do here I would say is to use an event. If the scope is isolated you can broadcast from the directive controller (or another controller) as in this answer:

[AngularJS : broadcast event from directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199212/angularjs-broadcast-event-from-directive)

Here's some code demonstrating what to do with isolate scopes and events, etc:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview

```
app.directive('post', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log('post');
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      tellComments = function() {
        console.log('telling comments');
        $scope.$broadcast('heyComments');
      };
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="tellComments()">sup</button><div comments></div>'
  };
})

app.directive('comments', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log('comments');
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.$on('heyComments', function() {
        console.log('sup post!');
      });
    }
  }
})
```

And the template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div post>
      <button ng-click="tellComments()">click me</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

So clicking the button, or doing anything else (e.g. loading some data) that calls the function 'tellComments' then gets sent into the child directive, handled by the controller scopes - NOT the same as the directive scopes.